# Prove $B=(A\cap B) \cup (B - A)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been trying to prove this but at the end I just end up doing the same thing over and over without getting somewhere. 
The problem is to prove $B=(A\cap B)\cup(B - A)$ using just basic operations: union, intersection, difference, symmetric difference and complement.

Comment: Prove two-sided inclusion: $\subset$ and $\supset$.

Comment: From Right to Left is quite obvious: $A \cap B$ is a subset of $B$ and also $B \setminus A$ is. Thus, their union will also be included into $B$.

Comment: Hint: For all $x \in B$, either $x \in A$ or $x\not\in A$

Comment: Also to get a feel of why this should be true and relate to the previous hint, draw a Venn diagram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(A\cap B) \cup (B - A)=(A\cap B) \cup (B\cap \bar A)=B \cap ( A \cup \bar A)=B \cap U=B$

Comment: Thank you so much